# What is the exact role of model $p_\theta$ in Diffusion models for the reverse process?

Tags: conditional-probability, generative-models, diffusion, langevin-diffusion

I'm reading this interesting [blog post](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/) explaining *Diffusion probabilistic models* and trying to understand the following.

In order to compute the *reverse process*, we need to consider the posterior distribution $q(\textbf{x}_{t-1} | \textbf{x}_t)$ which is said to be **intractable** *' because **it needs to use the entire dataset** and therefore we need to learn a model $p_\theta$ to approximate these conditional probabilities in order to run the reverse diffusion process'*.

If we use *Bayes theorem* we have

$$q(\textbf{x}_{t-1} | \textbf{x}_t) = \frac{q(\textbf{x}_t |\textbf{x}_{t-1})q(\textbf{x}_{t-1})}{q(\textbf{x}_t)}$$

I understand that indeed we don't have any prior knowledge of $q(\textbf{x}_{t-1})$ or $q(\textbf{x}_t)$ since this would mean already having the distribution we are trying to estimate. Is this correct?

The above posterior becomes **tractable** when conditioned on $\textbf{x}_0$ and we obtain

$$q(\textbf{x}_{t-1} | \textbf{x}_t , \textbf{x}_0) = \mathcal{N}(\tilde{\bf{\mu}}(\textbf{x}_t , \textbf{x}_0) \, , \, \tilde{\beta}_t \textbf{I})$$

So apparently we obtain a **posterior** that can be calculated in **closed form** when we condition on the original data $\textbf{x}_0$. At this point, I don't understand the role of the model $p_\theta$ : why do we need to tune the parameters of a model if we can already obtain our posterior?

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that indeed we don't have any prior knowledge of $q(x_{t−1})$ or $q(x_t)$ since this would mean already having the distribution we are trying to estimate. Is this correct?

Yes, I think that $q(x_{t-1})$ could only be estimated with an integration involving the whole dataset (which is **intractable**), as stated in this [blog](https://theaisummer.com/diffusion-models/).

> So apparently we obtain a posterior that can be calculated in closed form when we condition on the original data $x_0$. At this point, I don't understand the role of the model $p_\theta$: why do we need to tune the parameters of a model if we can already obtain our posterior?

Knowing only the distribution $q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)$ could not allow sampling, i.e. to generate images from noise, since $x_0$ is a sample from the training dataset.

That's why we want an estimate $p_\theta(x_{t-1}|x_t)$ of $q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)$, which allows to pass some noise $x_T \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbb{I})$ to the model and turn it into an image, with a sufficient number of denoising steps.

[image]